# Linker failed when archiving

Tags: swift, xcode, linker-errors, archiving

I have a problem with archiving my app. It's written all in `Swift 4`, all modules have the same build settings and `Deployment target` set to `11.2`. When testing app on device it works fine. When I try to archive or profile I get this error[image]

Don't really know what to do with this. I don't use any external libraries and everything is set the same way:

[image]

Comment: It's complaining about `arm64`, and in debug you've got it set for active architecture only...

Comment: But arm64 is set in `Valid architectures` for all targets. And also even if I set `NO` for `Debug` in `Build Active Architecture Only` its still working for debugging.

Comment: Have you cleaned your project? Try that. It looks like it's just missing the symbols in one file `FindloAugmentedRealityViewFinal`.

Comment: I did, many times. Cleaned project and build folder, didn't help

Answer (score 0):

I have found something else. I tried to make this functions public, and it worked. But these are all functions that I use only internally, so this should not be a problem. Does anyone know why this happens? In this picture there are fatal errors, but this functions are overwritten later in this target.

[image]

It also worked when I didn't make them public, but in later overrides didn't use final. Before these were final in subclasses, and when they are not it works. Don't know why, but I'll go with this.